# Migrating Spring 1.x upgrade to 4.x

Tags: java, spring

My system is quite old it is on spring 1.x, my question is if I need to upgrade it to spring 4.x, how would I do it? I haven found any documentation on how I could do so. Thanks

Comment: Migrating 3 whole major versions is quite a task. I doubt there's any migration guide that would take that into account.

Comment: I think it'd almost be easier to just rewrite the thing and take whatever Java code is needed from the old project that'd take more effort to rewrite from scratch... Spring Boot is amazing though, so it shouldn't be *that* hard. Just really tedious and it would take a while to preserve functionality from the old, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how complex your app is, and how much of Spring it uses. With each major release of Spring, significant chunks of older functionality were deprecated and/or removed.

If you jump straight from 1.x to 4.x, then your app will likely not work, or maybe even compile, unless its a fairly trivial app. Best do it in stages.

1. Upgrade your app from Spring 1.x to 2.0.x.
2. Upgrade your app from Spring 2.x to 3.1.x.
3. Upgrade your app from Spring 3.x to 4.x.

After each step, re-test your app thoroughly. Assuming it's still working, check all of your code looking for any usages of Spring API that are now deprecated in that version. If you find any, replace them with what that version recommends.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I am unable to find migration guides to do so from 1.x to 2.0.x, only from 2.x onwards am I able to find. google didn't help much, any ideas?

Comment: Spring 1.x is so old that you might be on your own there. Just try it.